# Use external stylesheet for Vue web component / Prevent inlining styles

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I am using an `vue-cli-service` to build a web component. All styles referenced in this component are always inlined into the javascript file.

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name component-name  --inline-vue  ./src/components/someComponent.vue
```

Is there a way to force Vue to pull out component CSS into a separate file instead of inlining it into the `dist/component-name.js` file?

Alternatively, is there an easy way to allow external users to override the Shadow DOM styles?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't believe there's an automated way to do this without writing a custom webpack plugin. You're going to have to migrate the CSS manually.

If you're using webpack, you can take all your component CSS and move it into a separate file.

From there, you can include it in your `main.js` file using either a `require` or an `import`:

```
import './css/styles.css';
```

If you're not using webpack or you want to include CSS files only in specific components then you can import the file within the component itself.

Simply create a `<style>` block and import the CSS within it:

```
<style>
  @import './css/styles.css';
</style>
```

You could use this `<style>` block approach globally too by adding it to your `App.vue` file.

Comment: That's the idea I had as well. Unfortunately, the `--target wc` to build a web component pulls in all external files as well, even disrespecting `css.extract` in `vue.config.js`.